# why dart didn't throw compile-time mistype exception instead. of run-time?

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, compile-time-type-checking

Consider this sample code:

```
void main() {

  List<int> array = <int>[];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array.add(i);
  }

  Iterable<int> newList = array.where( (value) =>  value % 2 == 0 );

  printFunction(array);
  printFunction(newList);
}

void printFunction(List<int> list) {
 print(list); 
}
```

This code compile successfully but of course throw an exception in runtime, because it can't run the code for `printFunction(newList)` unless calling `toList()` before passing `newList`

Why compiler didn't throw an exception in this case???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of check can be enabled via dart analyzer setting (analysis_options.yaml) as shown below:

```yaml
analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
```